# jQuery DataTables: Can I have 3 states for Sort : ASC, DESC and NO_SORT?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

jQuery Datatable's sorting order on clicking column header toggles only between asc(Down Arrow) and desc(Up Arrow). i.e.,

```
1st-click ascending
2nd-click descending
3rd-click asc
4th-click desc
   ||   || 
   ||   || 
   ||   || 
   ||   || 
odd-click asc
even-click desc.
```

I want to induce something like this :

```
1st-click ascending
2nd-click descending
3rd-click no-sorting
4th-click asc
5th-click desc
6th-click no-sort
   ||   || 
   ||   || 
   ||   || 
   ||   || 
(n%3==1)-click asc
(n%3==2)-click desc
(n%3==0)-click no-sort.
```

Is there a way to change this behavior in jQuery dataTables? Please help!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would be the difference between no-sort and the previous sort mode? The sort order wouldn't change. What are you trying to do?

Comment: All I am try to ask is once you apply a sort on a column. How do you remove it without having to sort any other column?

Comment: But what does removing a sort mean to you?

Comment: Let's say I have 3 cols : Age, name, DOB. Initially I display only the table rows in the order they are received from the Rest API. Then click on age column header once. The table gets sorted according to Age-asc. Now how do I remove this age sort and go back to the Initial ordering of the table rows as received from the API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, that was interesting. This should do what you need though it's not elegant:

```
$('#example').on("order.dt", function () {
    if(example.settings().order().length === 1){
        var order = example.settings().order()[0];
        var th = $("#example th:eq(" + order[0] + ")");
        if(th.attr("data-sort-next") === "false"){
            example.order([]).draw();
            th.attr("data-sort-next", true);
        }else{
            if(order[1] === "desc"){
                th.attr("data-sort-next", false);
            }else{
                th.attr("data-sort-next", true);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/sgq46j0b/) illustrates what's going on. Basically, what you want is available out of the box for multi-column sorting (as noted in the comments). What I've done is intercept the sorting if there's only one column being sorted, without messing up the multi-column sorting. I'll keep on trying to refine it but that should work for you.

Comment: Yeah this is good. As a suggestion, if you want to clear a single column in the midst of a multi column sort. You can do :example.order([col_idx, '']).draw(); to clear only 1 specific columns's sorting.

Comment: Although this is not required usually, unless like me you decide to bypass SHIFT and make multi-column the default behavior.

Comment: @jackOfAll An empty array does the same TBH ;-) I've updated the JSFiddle to make it a bit more elegant (there was an issue with the `data-attribute` not being cleared).

Answer (score 0):

when you load a table, it is sorted in a certain way (maybe by id, name or whatever). So what you call 'no-sorting' is, in fact, a 'sort by initial column'.

An easy approach is to let the sorting mechanism as it is, and place a button somewhere to reload the table deleting the current sort. Or even better, make this button sort the table by the initial column.

Comment: So there is no way to implement a 3  toggle state sorting out of the box?

Comment: I've been looking at this and there's a way of removing all sorting... `example.order([]).draw();`; but I'm having trouble figuring out how to selectively remove sorting for a given column.

Comment: @jackOfAll it can technically be done, take a look at https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/17910/three-states-of-a-header-sort-decoration. But why would you do that? think about it. If you want to remove the current sorting it's because you want to sort by another column!!

Comment: @Dacklf For example, you might have Used SHIFT+Click to select 4 different columns to sort by  a combo of them and then remove one of them(incase you have selected 1 column wrongly). Then you prefer to just click on the column a cpl of times holding SHIFT to just remove that columns sort.

Comment: @jackOfAll but this example you are giving is already a default! if you hold Shift and click 3 times in a column, it returns to it's previous sorting state

Comment: When I say previous state I mean the state before I applied sorting to that column. click 1 = asc, click 2 = desc, click 3 = remove sort, click 4= asc,.. If you see most other datatables follow this pattern

Comment: @jackOfAll that is exactly what datatables does. https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multi_col_sort.html. When you select a second column (with shift), it removes the sort on that column if you click a 3rd time...

Comment: Thanks that solves half my problems. But, I am also expected to remove the sort on 3rd click for a single column sort

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issued by maintaining the state of the columns an array, intercepting and stopping the default behavior of the order event and then manually doing :

```
var dir = 'asc' for ascending
var dir  ='desc' for descending
var dir = '' for no-sort

$("#table-id").dataTable.order([colIdx, dir]).draw();
```

Comment: does this workaround handle the icon of the sorting order right? I would like to see a jsFiddle out of curiosity. Also, mark your answer as accepted if it solves the question.

Comment: Yes this takes care of the icon. I'll try n put a jsFiddle this weekend.